# How to reverse “reversed” duplicated tuples from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I have a list of tuples:

```
a  = [(a,b), (a,b), (b,c), (b,a), (a,b), (c,b)]
```

How can I find all the 'reversed' duplicated tuples like `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`, `(b,c)` and `(c,b)`; and change elements inside tuples in a consistent order, so it can become:

```
a  = [(a,b), (a,b), (b,c), (a,b), (a,b), (b,c)]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your code and explain what difficulties you are having? Based on your examples, you are also looking to simply sort this thing in alphabetical order. Or is this just a coincidence based on your example?

Comment: `tuple(reversed(('a','b')))`  
`Out[11]: ('b', 'a')`

Comment: What's your expected output then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer

Convert tuples to list, sort the list, return it to a tuple type.

`def sort_tuples(alistoftuples):
    return [tuple(sorted(k)) for k in alistoftuples]`

Comment: I was thinking too complicated. I used if statement and nested for-loop to detect reversed duplicated...

Comment: No need to pass a list to sorted. You can just use `sorted(k)` here

Comment: Huh, ```sorted``` converts a tuple to a list and returns a list?
I didn't know it behaved that way.